# Style unordered list to put the disc inside list items

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I can't find the solution to this simple problem. I thought I could fix it with `box-sizing`, but it doesn't work.

I'm using a `disc` as `list-style` and I want it to be INSIDE my `li` and not over the left border of my element. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? How does your list looks like? Could you try to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Simply add [`list-style-position: inside;`](http://jsbin.com/jibik/1/watch?css,output)

Comment: Oh haha, I'm working with CSS like 1 year right now, and I've never heard of list-style-position. Thanks!

Comment: `boz-sizing` was a typo, right..? Incidentally, if your question is answered don't hide that in an edit to the question, add it as an answer. And accept that answer. That, or delete the question. @Hashem: please consider posting that as an answer so the question has an easily visible answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply achieve that by applying [`list-style-position: inside;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position) to the list items.

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/jibik/1/edit)**

```css
li {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

`list-style-position` is applicable to elements with `display: list-item`.

The CSS Level 2 Spec [states](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-position):

> **[12 Generated content, automatic numbering, and lists / 'list-style-position'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-list-style-position)**
>
> This property specifies the position of the marker box with respect to
>   the principal block box. Values have the following meanings:
>
> **'inside'** value:
>   The marker box is placed as the first inline box in the principal block box, before the element's content and before any
>   `:before` pseudo-elements. CSS 2.1 does not specify the precise location
>   of the marker box.